# iOS - Development build working but Distribution build crash

Tags: ios, xcode, configuration, build-process

I am facing issue/crash in distribution build app. But not in Development build. Development is running fine. (Distribution app validate successfully)

What is problem while I create distribution build. I checked all configs debug and release.

Here crash log : from device when I use Distribution (Distribution by AdHoc and upload to

```
Hardware Model:      iPhone4,1
Process:             AppName [513]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/F2922A29-2E11-4377-XXXX-327A3DFC4612/AppName.app/AppName
Identifier:          com.user.AppName
Version:             1.2.5 (1.2.5)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-11-12 13:05:32.465 +0530
Launch Time:         2014-11-12 12:59:08.534 +0530
OS Version:          iOS 8.1 (12B411)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xf0419f0b
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3083ef76 objc_msgSend + 22
1   AppName                 0x000d7cc0 -[AsyncUdpSocket doReceive:] (AsyncUdpSocket.m:2181)
2   AppName                 0x000d7fa0 -[AsyncUdpSocket doCFSocketCallback:forSocket:withAddress:withData:] (AsyncUdpSocket.m:2281)
3   AppName                 0x000d3e7c MyCFSocketCallback (AsyncUdpSocket.m:2297)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x22f9ce9c __CFSocketPerformV0 + 552
5   CoreFoundation                  0x22f9a5e4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
6   CoreFoundation                  0x22f999f6 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 218
7   CoreFoundation                  0x22f98074 __CFRunLoopRun + 764
8   CoreFoundation                  0x22ee597c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
9   CoreFoundation                  0x22ee578e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
10  GraphicsServices                0x2a2be04c GSEventRunModal + 132
11  UIKit                           0x264d797c UIApplicationMain + 1436
12  AppName                 0x000d80ca main (main.m:16)
13  AppName                 0x0009149c start + 36

)
```

I missed any configurations ?
Please help me for this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had this issue with AsyncUDPSocket and I believe it's because AsyncUDPSocket is not thread safe, and in debug mode you may be running only a single thread while in distribution, various optimizations will cause it to crash.

I've converted over to GDCAsyncUdpSocket and my distribution builds do not crash. Good luck!